Instagram Graph API - receiving IGTV media product type
Im using instagram graph API and im fetching user insights, with the metric of "reach" and a breakdown of "media_product_type".
For a specific user, in some recent days, I receive a product type of IGTV (as a breakdown, along all the others) with numbers greater than 0 (meaning the API says there's reach from IGTV).
The weird thing is IGTV doesnt exist anymore in Instagram, for a long time now. So I don't understand how the API tells there is reach from an IGTV media, and whether its a bug or related to reels.
